# Cannot execute gradle from the command line even though it's on my path

Tags: path, gradle, environment-variables, bash

I have the following in ./bash_profile

```
export SRCROOT=/users/benjamin.beasley/work/svn/ccdev
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk_dev/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH$:~/tools/tools-versions/gradle-2.2.1/bin
export PATH=$PATH$:~/tools/activator
```

In ~/tools/tools-versions/gradle-1.12/bin, I do

```
drwxr-xr-x@  4 xxx.xxx  WORKDAYINTERNAL\Domain Users   136 Nov 12 11:47 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 xxx.xxx  WORKDAYINTERNAL\Domain Users   442 Apr 29  2014 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 xxx.xxx  WORKDAYINTERNAL\Domain Users  5071 Apr 29  2014 gradle
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 xxx.xxx  WORKDAYINTERNAL\Domain Users  2395 Apr 29  2014 gradle.bat
```

echo $PATH$:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin$:/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/tools-versions/gradle-2.2.1/bin$:/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/activator90566
```

so I get the gradle executable which is executable. I can execute it from this directory. But if I start a new shell, and type "gradle" it says command not found. But I "echo $PATH$" and I see that the full canonical path to the ~/tools/tools-versions/gradle-2.2.1/bin folder is there.

However I can execute activator which is an executable in the ~/tools/activator directory. I have no clue why bash knows about activator and not gradle.

In summary:

1. gradle is executable by this user
2. gradle can be run from the command line.
3. gradle is in the $PATH$ environment variable
4. other programs such as activator, which are also in $Path$ are executable anywhere in terminal regardless of directory which is what I want to be true of gradle.

Comment: Unix environment variables are `$PATH` not `$PATH$` (they aren't like Windows env vars).

Comment: Also don't use `~` use `$HOME`.

Comment: Neither comment helped. Got any more ideas? :)

Comment: The first comment should have if you dropped all the final `$` and set your path cleanly. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unix environment variables are `$PATH` not `$PATH$` (they aren't like Windows env vars).

This is causing your problem.

This path is busted: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin$:/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/tools-versions/gradle-2.2.1/bin$:/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/activator90566`

Notice the `90566` at the end? That's from `$$` having been expanded to the current process id when you set the variable.

None of these are paths that actually exist or work:

```
/opt/X11/bin$
/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/tools-versions/gradle-2.2.1/bin$
/Users/xxx.xxx/tools/activator90566
```